# std::set difference with self defined type

Tags: c++, set, stl-algorithm

I've defined my own struct like

```cpp
struct element {

int id;
float value;
}
```

and I'm using it with `std::set`. I want to use the `set_difference` algorithm (like already mentioned in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459250/set-theory-data-structure) for determining the difference of two sets. When I try to invoke the code, compilation stops with the following error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:268: error: passing 
'const element' as 'this' argument of 'element& element::operator=(const element&)' 
discards qualifiers
```

A minimal example may look like this:

```cpp
std::set<struct element> s1;
std::set<struct element> s2;
std::set<struct element> s3;

element e1 = { 1, 11.0 };
element e2 = { 2, 22.0 };
element e3 = { 3, 33.0 };

s1.insert(e1);
s1.insert(e2);
s2.insert(e2);
s2.insert(e3);

set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), s3.begin());
```

Comment: Note: you don't need to write `struct` every time you refer to `element`.

Comment: Please can you post a self-contained example?

Comment: How does your set perform comparisons? Are you posting pseudo-code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
set_difference(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(),
               std::inserter(s3, s3.begin()));
//             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Example: http://ideone.com/B4Cc1

By putting `s3.begin()` as the output iterator, you would mean that you want to **overwrite** the front region of the set with the set difference. Overwriting requires the size of set being larger than the result, which is obviously not true most of the time; even if the set is not empty, you can't use `s3.begin()` as output because the iterator is read-only (otherwise it would destroy the sorted order).

OTOH, `std::inserter(x, cit)` means that, whenever this output iterator is assigned (`*it = y`), the insert method will be called (`x.insert(cit, y)`), which is what you really want: populate a set from empty.

Comment: This makes sense now, thank you. I was looking for an answer at the totally wrong part of the code. I thought there was something wrong with my `element struct` and one of it operators itself - which seems quite senseless to me now... Thank you again! @KennyTM